# Web App deployed in Kubernetes (AKS) 1.19 version returns 404 Page not found

Tags: kubernetes, http-status-code-404, azure-aks, traefik-ingress, azure-web-app-for-containers

We have a react node web application which is deployed in Azure Kubernetes. The app is currently deployed in AKS with Kubernetes version 1.15 but we want to upgrade the Kubernetes to 1.19. While deploying the app to AKS 1.19 we have made perquisite changes to multiple yaml files so that the app is compatible when deployed to AKS 1.19. After doing the relevant changes and deploying the app to AKS all the PODS - backend,frontend,traefik all come up and running ,we are using csi driver to mount the Azure KEY VAULT to the backend POD, Traefik is the ingress controller. Out put of - kubectl get pods after deploying the app to AKS 1.19

```
backend-xxx-backend-85595564fd-gbf84                        1/1     Running     0          143m
backend-xxx-backend-85595564fd-gcg9b                        1/1     Running     0          138m
backend-xxx-backend-85595564fd-m65pm                        1/1     Running     0          141m
csi-secrets-store-provider-azure-1615448315-4db78                 1/1     Running     0          5d8h
csi-secrets-store-provider-azure-1615448315-54xw7                 1/1     Running     0          5d8h
csi-secrets-store-provider-azure-1615448315-secrets-store-47wrp   3/3     Running     0          5d8h
csi-secrets-store-provider-azure-1615448315-secrets-store-8z6ck   3/3     Running     0          5d8h
csi-secrets-store-provider-azure-1615448315-secrets-store-tc4jq   3/3     Running     0          5d8h
csi-secrets-store-provider-azure-1615448315-vk6wb                 1/1     Running     0          5d8h
frontend-xxx-frontend-677cc59f57-6m9sn                      1/1     Running     0          139m
frontend-xxx-frontend-677cc59f57-tfnx7                      1/1     Running     0          138m
frontend-xxx-traefik-5c7dd459df-8c8m7                             1/1     Running     0          101m
frontend-xxx-traefik-5c7dd459df-m8lvc                             1/1     Running     0          101m
```

But when I try to access the app from the browser using the URL mention in the values.yaml as the host name it returns a - 404 Page Not Found error , we were expecting the login Page to get loaded.

Ingress Yaml - Front End :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1  
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}-ingress
  annotations:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.ingress.annotations }}
      {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
spec:
  rules:
    {{- range $host := .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ $fullname }}-svc
                port:
                  number: {{ $servicePort }}
    {{- end }}
```

Ingress Yaml - backend

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1  
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}-ingress
  annotations:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.ingress.annotations }}
      {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
spec:
  rules:
    {{- range $host := .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ $fullname }}-svc
                port: 
                  number: {{ $servicePort }}
       {{- end }}


PS C > kubectl describe Endpoints
Name:         backend-xxx-backend-svc
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  <none>
Subsets:
  Addresses:          10.26.240.20,10.26.240.41,10.26.240.90
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name     Port  Protocol
    ----     ----  --------
    <unset>  8800  TCP

Events:  <none>


Name:         frontend-xxx-frontend-svc
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  <none>
Subsets:
  Addresses:          10.26.240.50,10.26.240.69
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name     Port  Protocol
    ----     ----  --------
    <unset>  80    TCP

Events:  <none>


Name:         frontend-xxx-traefik
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app=traefik
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              chart=traefik-1.64.0
              heritage=Helm
              release=frontend-xxx
Annotations:  endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: 2021-03-16T14:18:58Z
Subsets:
  Addresses:          10.26.240.54,10.26.240.82
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name   Port  Protocol
    ----   ----  --------
    http   80    TCP
    https  8880  TCP

Events:  <none>


Name:         kubernetes
Namespace:    default
Labels:       endpointslice.kubernetes.io/skip-mirror=true
Annotations:  <none>
Subsets:
  Addresses:          52.139.10.83
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name   Port  Protocol
    ----   ----  --------
    https  443   TCP

Events:  <none>


PS C > kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
default       backend-xxx-backend-svc     ClusterIP      192.168.244.160   <none>         80/TCP                       22h
default       eyvia-reportingservice-svc        ClusterIP      192.168.154.18    <none>         80/TCP                       22h
default       frontend-xxx-frontend-svc   ClusterIP      192.168.55.108    <none>         80/TCP                       22h
default       frontend-xxx-traefik              LoadBalancer   192.168.88.230    10.26.240.97   80:30469/TCP,443:30098/TCP   22h
default       kubernetes                        ClusterIP      192.168.0.1       <none>         443/TCP                      8d
kube-system   healthmodel-replicaset-service    ClusterIP      192.168.204.55    <none>         25227/TCP                    8d
kube-system   kube-dns                          ClusterIP      192.168.0.10      <none>         53/UDP,53/TCP                8d
kube-system   metrics-server                    ClusterIP      192.168.133.206   <none>         443/TCP                      8d

PS C> kubectl get ing -A
NAMESPACE   NAME                                  CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
default     backend-xxx-backend-ingress     <none>   *                 80      22h
default     frontend-xxx-frontend-ingress   <none>   *                 80      22h

PS C:> kubectl get ing -A -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: 'server:'
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
      meta.helm.sh/release-name: backend-prd
      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
    creationTimestamp: "2021-03-17T12:22:10Z"
    generation: 1
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    managedFields:
    - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: {}
            f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
        f:spec:
          f:rules: {}
      manager: Go-http-client
      operation: Update
      time: "2021-03-17T12:22:10Z"
    name: backend-xxx-backend-ingress
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "1960069"
    selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/backend-xxx-backend-ingress
    uid: 20308a3e-76ad-4286-a91c-c05a7d7b94ba
  spec:
    rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: backend-xxx-backend-svc
            servicePort: 80
          path: /api/
          pathType: Prefix
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
      ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: 'server:'
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
      meta.helm.sh/release-name: frontend-prd
      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
    creationTimestamp: "2021-03-17T12:22:27Z"
    generation: 1
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    managedFields:
    - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: {}
            f:ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: {}
            f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
        f:spec:
          f:rules: {}
      manager: Go-http-client
      operation: Update
      time: "2021-03-17T12:22:27Z"
    name: frontend-xxx-frontend-ingress
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "1960242"
    selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/frontend-xxx-frontend-ingress
    uid: 7f102b21-23d0-49cc-86b7-24a002050d04
  spec:
    rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: frontend-xxx-frontend-svc
            servicePort: 80
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""



PS C:> kubectl describe po frontend-xxx-traefik-5c7dd459df-8g94r
Name:               frontend-xxx-traefik-5c7dd459df-8g94r
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               aks-agentpool-27227329-vmss000002/10.26.240.66
Start Time:         Wed, 17 Mar 2021 17:52:27 +0530
Labels:             app=traefik
                    chart=traefik-1.64.0
                    heritage=Helm
                    pod-template-hash=5c7dd459df
                    release=frontend-xxx
Annotations:        checksum/config: 17af10aa3c1f384e3e5ec092c07352acc76bc89571785250128fd4e44a3e94ec
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.26.240.79
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/frontend-xxx-traefik-5c7dd459df
Containers:
  frontend-xxx-traefik:
    Container ID:  containerd://e7c7966dec5283c5e36cc0089ee5b1ae1cb535bdac73d750045f518a51ba35c8
    Image:         traefik:1.7.9
    Image ID:      docker.io/library/traefik@sha256:6348d14975b683a2783cc8dbaa76efe5367a1d67bd3e9e2ee812da7da012224b
    Ports:         80/TCP, 8880/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      --configfile=/config/traefik.toml
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 17 Mar 2021 17:52:29 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       tcp-socket :80 delay=10s timeout=2s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      tcp-socket :80 delay=10s timeout=2s period=10s #success=1 #failure=1
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /config from config (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-h9kch (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      frontend-xxx-traefik
    Optional:  false
  default-token-h9kch:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-h9kch
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

We use Traefik as Ingress Controller in our deployment and when I see the logs for the Traefik pod I just see this - Looks like the loglevel is set as info   :

```
E0317 16:00:04.641113       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: v1.ServiceList.Items: []v1.Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, but found p, error found in #10 byte of ...|:{},"k:{\"port\":80,|..., bigger context ...|anaged-by":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:port":|...
E0317 16:00:05.644045       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: v1.ServiceList.Items: []v1.Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, but found p, error found in #10 byte of ...|:{},"k:{\"port\":80,|..., bigger context ...|anaged-by":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:port":|...
E0317 16:00:06.646728       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: v1.ServiceList.Items: []v1.Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, but found p, error found in #10 byte of ...|:{},"k:{\"port\":80,|..., bigger context ...|anaged-by":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:port":|...
E0317 16:00:07.649633       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: v1.ServiceList.Items: []v1.Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, but found p, error found in #10 byte of ...|:{},"k:{\"port\":80,|..., bigger context ...|anaged-by":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:port":|...
E0317 16:00:08.652654       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: v1.ServiceList.Items: []v1.Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, but found p, error found in #10 byte of ...|:{},"k:{\"port\":80,|..., bigger context ...|anaged-by":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:port":|...
E0317 16:00:09.654701       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: v1.ServiceList.Items: []v1.Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, but found p, error found in #10 byte of ...|:{},"k:{\"port\":80,|..., bigger context ...|anaged-by":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:port":|...
E0317 16:00:10.656995       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: v1.ServiceList.Items: []v1.Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, but found p, error found in #10 byte of ...|:{},"k:{\"port\":80,|..., bigger context ...|anaged-by":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:port":|...
E0317 16:00:11.659811       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: v1.ServiceList.Items: []v1.Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, but found p, error found in #10 byte of ...|:{},"k:{\"port\":80,|..., bigger context ...|anaged-by":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:port":|...
E0317 16:00:12.662628       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: v1.ServiceList.Items: []v1.Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, but found p, error found in #10 byte of ...|:{},"k:{\"port\":80,|..., bigger context ...|anaged-by":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:port":|...
E0317 16:00:13.665582       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: v1.ServiceList.Items: []v1.Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, but found p, error found in #10 byte of ...|:{},"k:{\"port\":80,|..., bigger context ...|anaged-by":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:port":|...
```

Any Pointers as to what we are missing and why do we end up with **404 Page not found** will be very help full.

Is there any config that we are missing.

Comment: Can't you check your frontend webserver logs to see which URL is actually retrieved or let me rather say trying to get retrieved? This should give you some indication where you are being led to. accordingly you then need to adjust.

Comment: Can you share the output of `kubectl get ing -A`, `kubectl get svc -A`, `kubectl describe endpoint frontend-svc`,  and the exact URL you are browsing?

Comment: The provided ingress yamls are useless without values that backs them. Would you expect us to guess them? 404 usually means that ingress does not find the service to forward the traffic to.

Comment: I wanted to see if your kube services are bound and they are bound correctly. Next item would be what @thomas suggested. Getting the actual yaml manifest of the ingress. `kubectl get ing -A -o yaml`. Also shared the logs of the ingress controller showing errors. That should be enough information to identify the issue

Comment: Also, please note that this is a pretty common error and most of the times it's a user configuration error.

Comment: @Faheem - I am updating the output of the command in the question. Also I have just started to work on AKS so appologise if i miss something.

Comment: Also Since my App is running on AKS 1.19.7 do i need to deploy IngressClass as well along with Ingress

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is not clear from the description, I am going to suggest following items for debugging.

1. Tail the logs of traefik controller pods to make sure you are getting traffic when you access the target URL. Beware of browser caches, either do `cURL` or browse using a new incognito window. Tail logs from all controller pods, you may have multiple pods handling the traffic. If you don't see any hits in the controller logs, there could be multiple issues. Check if your ingress controller is exposed correctly. Check the services running in the cluster by running `kubectl get svc -A`. See if traefik service is type LB. Get the service description and note any issues in the events section. If it's not configured and you see errors, delete the traffic chart and redeploy it. If it still doesn't come up right, open a support ticket with Azure team from the portal. However, if the LB is bound correctly. Check if you have access to the subnet where LB is running. There could also be a case where you have multiple ingress controllers installed and you hit the wrong controller. In that case, you should have multiple LB's created as well. Make sure you hitting the desired LB.
2. If you see errors in the logs, follow the errors. It will show upstream errors if it can't find the underlined services or if pods are denying traffic.
3. Ingress controllers are reverse proxies that are configured through kubernetes objects. If you are using path based routing, make sure your application listens on the path. For example, the backend traffic is being redirected to the `/api` path. If the app listens on `/` instead then it would fail. Also check-out rewrite-target and related annotations for proper configuration.
4. If you are using host based routing, make sure you are accessing the services with the correct hostname. Get a DNS name for the LB IP, alternatively modify you `hosts` file and then try the URL.